# Count of items under recursive categories

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query

I have two table. Tables name of *categories* and *items*.  I want to list category with item count.

*categories* table:

```
id | parent | catname | catpath
1    0        A         1
2    0        B         2
3    1        A1        1,3
4    3        A11       1,3,4
5    2        B1        2,5
6    0        C         6
```

....

*items* table:

```
id | catid | title
1    1       title1
2    1       title2
3    3       title3
4    4       title4
5    4       title5
6    3       title6
7    5       title7
```

And I want print categories like this:
print catname (itemcount = own item count + sub category's item count)

```
A (4)   /*<- sub category's item count + own item count*/
   A1 (1)
   A11 (2)
B (1)
   B1 (1)
```

UPDATE:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b3d4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this because you have the full path in the categories table.  Kudos.  So, you don't need a recursive query:

```
select c.catname, count(ic.catid) as cnt
from categories c left outer join
     (select i.*, c.catname, c.catpath
      from items i join
           categories c
           on i.catid = c.id
     ) as ic
     on concat(ic.catpath, ',') like concat(c.catpath, ',%')
group by c.catname;
```

This uses `like` to traverse the hierarchy.  The reason for the `,` is so 1 doesn't match 10.

Comment: I have an issue. When I add a category catname = C. I can't see result C. If hasn't items for C category not give this row.

Comment: @maverabil . . . A `left outer join` fixes that problem.